# Only show current workspace applications in Avant Window Navigator

Tags: dock

In [AWN](https://launchpad.net/awn) is it possible to only show applications that are on the current workspace?

I know its possible in Docky, but can't find any config for AWN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using Avant now (in 11.04), so, cannot check for sure, but in 10.10 I used it instead of the gnome panel: unless something has recently changed, there is an option in Preferences (right click > Dock preferences) under General that says something like "Show windows from all viewports". If you uncheck it, it will show windows from one workspace only.

Comment: Hi, I've had another look and it looks like there is option "show all windows" if you untick this it does show only the correct desktop ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of AWN (v0.4.1) on Ubuntu 12.04, you can change this setting by going to Preferences->Task Manager and unchecking "Show all windows".